# Putting sequential numbers in Attribute table

Tags: attribute-table

When I use the field calculator in the attribute table and use $rownum, the numbers appear as "1, 10, 100" instead of "1, 2, 3, 4."

How do I make it sequential?

Comment: Wich software are you using? ArcGIS, QGIS, another?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have `String`s instead of `Integer`s. Check what the type of the attribute is when you create it. [image]